# How to miss points in a ZedGraph line graph in C#

Tags: c#, zedgraph, points

I have bit of code that draws nice line charts in [ZedGraph](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/zedgraph.aspx).

I can not change the code entirely, but I would like to have some of the lines not have a y value for each point on the x-axis.

I can do this in Excel, but I don't know how to in ZedGraph.
I create graph with `.AddCurve`.

How do I do this?

Comment: Do you just want to not add data-points, or do you want the lines to be noncontinuous (with breaks in between)?

Comment: Bobby,no-continuous. so maybe a line has (1,1.2),(2,1.21),(3,1,22) and I want to plot (2,1.2105) but have no y values for x=1 or x=3. This obviously is super-simplified!

Comment: @ManInMoon: "I have bit of code" - please add the code to the question using the `edit` link.  Also, include an image of what your desired graph looks like (created in excel, possibly)

Comment: Justin - I tried to add an image but the browse... button doesn't do anything - am I doing something wrong? I expected it to bring up a file selection menu- I tried it many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NaN` values should do the trick.

If you want to break the line for example between x=1 and x=2, just add a point (1.5, double.NaN). Zedgraph should make the gap by itself.