# Plotting data with gaps in ZedGraph using nullable types / null values

Tags: c#, zedgraph

This question is very similar: [How to miss points in a zedgraph line graph in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154848/how-to-miss-points-in-a-zedgraph-line-graph-in-c).

I am pulling data from SQL and plotting it using ZedGraph, but I am using nullable types (`int?`, `float?` etc.) and would like to create gaps in the plot wherever a null value exists.

Is there a way to have ZedGraph handle these null values, or do I need to convert them all to `double.NaN`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting nullable types to `double.NaN` seems like the only option when creating the `PointPairList` for a ZedGraph `LineItem` (or whatever graph type). Using the [null-coalescing operator (??)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) makes this rather simple:

```
// example, adding one data point to the list
int? SomeValue = null;
myPointPairList.Add(x, SomeValue ?? double.NaN);
```